# Time reversal in Maxwell's electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, time-reversal-symmetry

The statement of the time-reversal invariance of Maxwell's electromagnetism, as I understand it, is the following.

Given $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)$ and $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t)$ that satisfy all Maxwell's equations (with $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t)$ and $\rho(\mathbf{r},t)$) and the boundary conditions, then the fields defined by
$$\mathbf{E'}(\mathbf{r},t) \equiv \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},-t), $$
$$\mathbf{B'}(\mathbf{r},t) \equiv \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},-t), $$
satisfy Maxwell's equations, with 
$$\mathbf{J'}(\mathbf{r},t) \equiv \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},-t), $$
$$\rho'(\mathbf{r},t) \equiv \rho(\mathbf{r},-t). $$

(It would be nice for me to find out that I understand time-reversal incorrectly.)

Just two of Maxwell's equations (div equations) were fine with me. For example, a problem arises with the following equation:
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t},$$
when replacing $t\rightarrow-t$:
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},-t)=+\frac{\partial \mathbf{B
}(\mathbf{r},-t)}{\partial t},$$
using our definitions:
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E'}(\mathbf{r},t)=+\frac{\partial \mathbf{B'}(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t}.$$

Comment: Looking at Ampere's law (or equivalently, the Biot-Savart law), you'll see that under time reversal, B should be transformed to -B.

Comment: I don't see a question here...?

Comment: It seems that the OP assumed the question is obvious: it's probably about how the incorrect positive sign in the last equation arose.

Answer (score 5):

When you perform a time reversal, you have to not only change the sign of $t$ everywhere, but also change the sign of some of the other physical quantities involved.  Time reversal symmetry just means that the *form* of all equations involved is the same after making the appropriate transformations.

If two quantities are related by a time derivative, they need to be opposite as to whether they are "even" (no sign change) or "odd" (changes sign) under the time reversal transformation.  For examples, a particle's position is even under the transformation, $r'(t)=r(-t)$, so the position's time derivative (the velocity) must be odd, $v'(t)= - v(-t)$, and so the velocity's time derivative (acceleration) must be even, $a'(t)=a(-t)$.  If you assume that mass doesn't change sign under the transformation, then force must be even under the transformation because acceleration is, so that $F=ma$ will continue to hold.  If you then assume that charge doesn't change sign under the transformation, then the electric field $E$ must be even, so that $E=F/q$ will continue to hold.  But $B$ and $E$ are related via a time derivative (the Maxwell–Faraday equation), so $B$ must be odd under the time reversal transformation.  Thus, the correct expression for the transformation of $B$ is $B'(r,t)= - B(r, -t)$.

For a larger list of which physical quantities are even vs. odd under a time reversal transformation, see the [T-symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Effect_of_time_reversal_on_some_variables_of_classical_physics) Wikipedia article.

Comment: You can also arrive at this conclusion about the magnetic field by realizing that $F = q v \times B$ has to be invariant, so the minus sign in v has to be cancelled by a minus sign in B.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field is a pseudovector and will therefore pick up a minus sign under reflections or time inversion.

Comment: B being a pseudovector doesn't tell us anything about its behavior under time reversal.